# Silverlight Navigation Menu

Tags: silverlight, menu, navigation

I am using the Silverlight Business Application Template.  The navigation consists of a few HyperlinkButtons in a StackPanel.  I would like to create a more robust navigation menu (multilevel) with dropdowns and such.  Telerik has one for silverlight (http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Menu/FirstLook)

I don't want to use Telerik control because its too expensive and I have tons of problems with Telerik.  I've Googled it but including "Navigation" in my search seems to only include results about the navigation framework.

Anyway, anyone have a good example?

Comment: check out this. http://silverlightpopupmenu.codeplex.com/

Comment: I had the same problem and finally built my own menu. You can see the demo and download it there: http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/